# What is 'step' object in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm unable to understand the following codes

1. `$(this).animate({rotate3Di: degrees}, options)`. Here `rotate3Di` is
   not a css property to animate.
2. `$.fx.step.rotate3Di = function(){}`. Here, they are adding a method
   called `rotate3Di` to `step`. What is `step`, `fx`. I'm sure that
   when we add a method to `$.fn` we will be able to access that method
   in jquery's result set. But by adding a method to `step`, where can
   we access it?

Got this plugin from http://www.zachstronaut.com/projects/rotate3di/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.fx.step` is an object containing functions that increment the animation by one iteration.
 The way animation works in jQuery (roughly) is the `$.animate()` method is called on an element and sets up an **interval/timeout**. Then each time the timeout/interval fires jQuery cycles through each property in the object passed to  `.animate()`, calling the default incrementation function (which just alters that css property slightly) if `$.fx.step[propertyName]` doesn't exist. But if `$.fx.step[propertyName]` *does* exist then that function gets called instead.

You can access the method `$.fx.step.rotate3Di()` directly (although it doesn't make sense to as all it would do, assuming that you pass in the expected parameters, is carry out a single non-animated rotation). It's not a jQuery plugin in the conventional sense, so you can't call `$(selector).rotate3di()`.